# Neo4J Load CSV -> URI is not hierarchical

Tags: neo4j

I try to import CSV in a Neo4j Database and I have a problem.

On my desktop computer (windows 7, java 1.8.0_40-b25), the LOAD CSV works great. 
But on the server (windows 2012 R2, java 1.8.0_65-b17), i have this error message "URI is not hierarchical".

I try to put the data on C:, F: ... no change.

Here's the code :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:F:/Neo4JData/Destination.csv"
AS line
MERGE (d:Destination {`Code`: line.`Code`});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using 2.3.0 Community Edition?

try:

> USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM
>   'file:///F:\\Neo4JData\\Destination.csv

Comment: Yes, I installed it today

Answer (score 7):

Create an import folder in the default path of the DB and place the file there that helped me.

For example: C:\Users\XXXXY\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import and put the csv there. In the query use 
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///customers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName, customerID: row.CustomerID, fax: row.Fax, phone: row.Phone});

Comment: On Linux it's $HOME/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-XXX/installation-XXX/import (where XXX are some numbers).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I solved it by putting `///` instead of `F:/` or `F:///`.

So if your source is

```
F:/FolderOne/FolderTwo/file.csv
```

It becomes

```
///FolderOne/FolderTwo/file.csv
```

Remember that in order to add the file you must put `file:` in front of the source.
So finally

```
file:///FolderOne/FolderTwo/file.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the future, try to make use of the markdown syntax to structure and format your posts for better readability. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As specified above once you try with

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///E:/AdventureWorks/adventureworks-neo4j/data/products.csv" as row
CREATE (:Product {productName: row.ProductName, productNumber: row.ProductNumber, productId: row.ProductID, modelName: row.ProductModelName, standardCost: row.StandardCost, listPrice: row.ListPrice});
```

The "URI is not hierarchical" error disappears. Then most probably you will get an error saying that it couldnt load the resource like

```
TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure
```

In order to solve the same you should find the neo4j.conf file.

Since i'm using a windows 10 machine and community edition of neo4j i could find the same in the below path.

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition
```

Edit the conf file and comment out the line

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

Doing the above steps enabled me to load the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

The file path seems wrong, can you try with :

```
"file:F:///Neo4JData/Destination.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem is still here :/

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
file:///F:/Neo4JData/Destination.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the .csv into the $NEO4JHOME/default.graphdb/import directory worked. You may have to create the folder, or maybe uncommenting the dbms.directories.import=import line in conf might do it. I dunno, did it the hard way :)

However, I found that I still had to include the drive specifier, i.e., file:///c:\csv2import.csv even if it wasn't in the root but in the import directorry

Answer (score 0):

Use the path 'file:///F:/Neo4JData/Destination.csv' and add the Destination.csv file to the neo4jDB\import directory.If the import directory is not there create a new directory named as import and add the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder import under `default.graphdb` and place your csv files there. Later, you can use file:///fileName.csv in your LOAD CSV query

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem as well so what I did was to copy the folder in which the .csv file was present to the following location:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-27badd10-8989-482d-871b-cad746091f07\installation-3.3.3\import\

it seems when neo4j is installed and we try to import data from files by giving "file:///c://........" then neo4j starts looking for that file in the location C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-27badd10-8989-482d-871b-cad746091f07\installation-3.3.3\import\

i.e the import folder. So we have to copy all the files needed to be imported by this this type of statement in that import folder.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked at my end in windows

> LOAD CSV FROM 'File:///order-details.csv' AS row
> RETURN count(row);

[image]