# Import csv file in neo4j from local disk

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

I am facing difficulty in importing a csv file in neo4j. I am working on Windows I have been trying this:

```
      LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:/path/to/data.csv" as submissions create (a1:Submission {preview: submissions.preview, secure_media_embed: submissions.secure_media_embed, media: submissions.media, secure_media: submissions.secure_media, media_embed: submissions.media_embed})
```

Getting error:

```
    URI is not hierarchical
```

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong here, I have been following blogs and all suggests this

Comment: Check this question: [Neo4J Load CSV -> URI is not hierarchical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481042/neo4j-load-csv-uri-is-not-hierarchical). The [Neo4j tutorial](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) was written for 2.x and I guess you're using 3.x. Also check the latest Cypher docs on [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/).

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas Solution from poonam Sampat (Neo4J Load CSV -> URI is not hierarchical) worked for me. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4J Load CSV -> URI is not hierarchical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481042/neo4j-load-csv-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

Answer (score 3):

Edit the neo4j conf file (/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf)

change the below line

***dbms.directories.import=import***

to

***dbms.directories.import=/home/suyati/Downloads/***

for loading a file from downloads.

In neo4j browser:

***load csv with headers from "file:///1.csv" as row***

(Your file should be there like /home/suyati/Downloads/1.csv)

Its will works fine.